# How to get all rows where date is in a specific range at a given period?

Tags: mysql, sql, date

How can I select all rows from a table where a date column is within a specific range of dates, at a given period (e.g. every 14 days)?

The table has a date column with most every date represented, possibly multiple times. The range is defined by a start date and an end date. The period is a number of days. For example:

- Start: 2016-01-01 (friday)
- End: 2016-12-31 (saturday)
- period: 14 (days)

For the above, the query should return rows for every other Friday in 2016. That is, it should return the rows for the following dates:

```
2016-01-01
2016-01-15
2016-01-29
2016-02-12
2016-02-26
2016-03-11
2016-03-25
2016-04-08
2016-04-22
2016-05-06
2016-05-20
2016-06-03
2016-06-17
2016-07-01
2016-07-15
2016-07-29
2016-08-12
2016-08-26
2016-09-09
2016-09-23
2016-10-07
2016-10-21
2016-11-04
2016-11-18
2016-12-02
2016-12-16
2016-12-30
```

Currently, this is done in a stored procedure where a loop fills a temp table with the target dates, which is later joined on. However, I am trying to rewrite this code to step away from stored procedures.

What would be the best way to get the desired rows without using the stored procedure & a temp table? Keep in mind that (one of) the table(s) is quite large at around 1M records indexed on date, so any calculated values might impact the performance severely.

Alternatively, I could calculate all dates in the interval in PHP/RoR and use a massive IN clause, but hopefully there is a better solution.

Comment: where ...datecolname between lowvalue and highvalue

Comment: Can you explain what the interval means here? Why not just use `mycolumn between start_date and end_date`?

Comment: Why step away from stored procedures? They are here exactly for this purpose.

Comment: Updated question to explain interval. BETWEEN wont work here.

Comment: Combine date BETWEEN start_date AND end_date with MODULO(date - start_date, 14) = 0.

Comment: SPs don't really play nice with Ruby on Rails and are, for the most part, not database agnostic. I prefer to use regular queries over SPs regarding idempotent requests.

Comment: i don't think it's wrong to calculate the dates in php and then use an IN clause, there are other solutions but they might fail to use the index

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- `table_name1` is your table
- `date1` the date field
- `"2022-01-02"` the start (twice included)
- `"2022-01-10"` the end
- `3` the interval

```
    SELECT date1
    FROM table_name1
    WHERE date1 BETWEEN "2022-01-02" AND "2022-01-10"
    AND (DATE("2022-01-02") - date1) % 3 = 0;
```

Tested it with MySQL 5.6.